# How can Python string become a variable?

Tags: python

I have seveval str like bellow:

```
str1 = "Seagate SATA___1000"
str2 = "Seagate SATA___1200"
str3 = "Seagate SSD___512"
str4 = "Seagate SSD___512"
str5 = "Seagate SSD___512"
str6 = "Seagate SSD___512"
str7 = "Seagate SSD___512"
str8 = "Seagate SSD___512"
str9 = "Seagate SSD___512"
str10 = "Seagate SSD___512"
```

I want to calculate the total size of them, so I constructed the bellow function:

```
def get_all_size():

    total_size = 0

    for i in range(1, 11):

        str_tmp = 'str'
        if i != 1:
            str_tmp += str(i)

        total_size += int(re.findall(r"\d+\.?\d*", str_tmp)[-1])  # there how to let the `str_tmp` to be the variable?
```

But, obviously, the `str_tmp` is not the variable, it is a string.

How to realize my requirement ?

Comment: You can hack it through `locals` but the better approach will be to store the strings in a list rather than separate variables, then you can simply iterate the list

Comment: How about you put those str1..10 in a list and iterate through them?

Comment: The javascript can do this.

Comment: 1. Variable variables are a bad idea in any language. 2. Even in Javascript you'll have a pretty hard time doing this without `eval`. 3. Just because another language "can do it" doesn't mean it's a good idea to do it in *this* language.